# How to create a custom template tag that passes in a dictionary of more than one object in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to create a template tag that passes in a dictionary of objects

models.py

```
class Notification(models.Models):
    name = models.CharField()
    ..........


template_tag.py
```

created a template tag that gets all the objects that I want to display

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def notifications():
    context = {'notifications':Notification.objects.order_by('-date')[:4]}
    return context
```

The later initiate a forloop that displays the objects

```
{% load template_tag %}

{% for obj in notifications %}
   <a href="">{{ obj.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope you get the idea.....

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I have found that django as something called "inclusion_tag"
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

create an html file and call it "notifications.html"

```
@register.inclusion_tag('notifications.html')
def notifications(total = 5):
    context = {'notifications':Notification.objects.order_by('-date')[:total]}
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in python:

```py
{% for key, value in notifications.items %} 
  <a href="#">{{key}} - {{value}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

As simple as that!